# React style by class name

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm implementing a sidebar following [this](https://jsfiddle.net/davidg707/cc96ku6t/1/) example but can't figure out how to apply the styles for each className...

This is what I've tried, but there are no styles applied...

Component:

```
import React from 'react';

import styles from '../stylesheets/menu.css';

var Parent = React.createClass({
  getInitialState(){
    return {sidebarOpen: false};
  },
  handleViewSidebar(){
    this.setState({sidebarOpen: !this.state.sidebarOpen});
  },
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header onClick={this.handleViewSidebar} />
        <SideBar isOpen={this.state.sidebarOpen} toggleSidebar={this.handleViewSidebar} />
        <Content isOpen={this.state.sidebarOpen} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var SideBar = React.createClass({
  render() {
    var sidebarClass = this.props.isOpen ? 'sidebar open' : 'sidebar';
    return (
      <div className={sidebarClass}>
        <div>I slide into view</div>
        <div>Me too!</div>
        <div>Meee Threeeee!</div>
        <button onClick={this.props.toggleSidebar} className="sidebar-toggle">Toggle Sidebar</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

export default Parent;
```

Styles:

```
.sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
}
.sidebar-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
}
.sidebar.open {
    left: 0;
}
```

webpack.config :

```
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'css-loader'
      }
    ]
  }
```

Partial folder structure:

client
--stylesheets
----menu.css
--components
----Sidebar.js

Comment: When I use webpack I use a link tag in my index.html file to use my styles. E.g. `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">`. Have you tried this method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are importing the styles as an object:

```
import styles from '../stylesheets/menu.css';
```

This can be used for CSS-in-JS, but in your case it will not work.

Try changing it to:

```
import '../stylesheets/menu.css';
```

And it should correctly apply the styles.

Comment: There are still no styles applied ... I updated the question with the `webpack.config` file content if it helps

Comment: Can you try replacing your `css-loader` with `style-loader!css-loader` in the webpack config (don't forget to actually npm install `style-loader` first)

Comment: I also created a WebpackBin that you can try out: https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-Kp_LIyM3OLRSAmis4L-
You can even download it to see the webpack config it uses!

Comment: @SimonNußbaumer Way cool. I didn't even know that webpack bin was a thing.